# How to databind a combobox column in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridviewcombobox

My situation is below:

I defied a class called "Student", it is as simple as below:

```
public Student
{
   Public string Name;
   Public List<string> Subjects;
}
```

Then I defined a `List<Student>` called `studentList`.

How can I combine this `studentList` with a `DataGridView`? The second column in the `DataGridView` should be a combobox listing all the subjects for the student.

Comment: I guess you will have to loop and assign the Subjects list as `DataSource` to the combobox

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for a TreeView or ListView to me, assuming that you are not using the combo boxes to select anything but to just view something.